# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.Esp_Index'. Did you mean 'auth.login' instead?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a simple signup and login form but I'm getting below error. I've tried to fix it by going through the documentation but no luck. can you please help.

**"werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.Esp_Index'. Did you mean 'auth.login' instead?"**

code in ****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '\xbd\xc5H\xe5\xd0rX\xcc\x11\x99'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://support:support@rea-lnx-tdin01:5432/postgres'

    db.init_app(app)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    return app
```

Code in **auth.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect

auth = Blueprint('auth',__name__)


@auth.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
   
    return render_template('Loginpage.html')

   
@auth.route('/Esp_Index', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def registration():
    #return '<h1> welcome to Index page </h1>'
    return render_template('Esp_Index.html')
```

Html Templates

**Code in Base Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script >
  <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/Styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <!-- //Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">    <!-- //web font -->

    {% endblock %}

</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" >
        <a href="{{url_for('auth.Esp_Index')}}" />

        <a href="{{url_for('auth.login')}}" />

        {% block content %}

            {% endblock %}
    </div>
            <ul class="colorlib-bubbles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
```

**Code in Esp_Index.html**

```
{% extends "ESP_Base.html" %}
{% block title %}Web Console{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Web Console SignUp Portal Form</h1>
{% with errors = get_flashed_messages() %}
     {% if errors %}
       {% for error in errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
  <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
        <div class="main-agileinfo">
            <div class="agileits-top">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input  type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="{{request.form.get.Username}}">
                    <input  type="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" value="{{request.form.get.Email}}">
                    <input  type="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" value="{{request.form.get.Password}}">
                    <input  type="Password" name="RepeatPassword" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" value="{{request.form.get.RepeatPassword}}">
                    <input type="submit" value="SIGNUP">
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="{{ url_for('login') }} "> Login Now!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Code in Loginpage.html**

```
{% extends "ESP_Base.html" %}
{% block title %}Web Console {% endblock %}
{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Web Console SignUp Portal Form</h1>
{% with errors = get_flashed_messages() %}
     {% if errors %}
       {% for error in errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
 <div class="main-agileinfo">
            <div class="agileits-top">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input  type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" value="{{request.form.get.Username}}">
                    <input  type="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" value="{{request.form.get.Password}}">
                    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Login"/></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The function name is `registration()`, not `Esp_Index()`.  The @auth.route decorator has Esp_Index, but that's different.

Answer (score 1):

When build a URL with [`url_for()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) in Flask, you should pass the endpoint of the view function, the default value of endpoint is **the name of the view function**, not the URL rule.

So you should write this in your template:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('auth.registration') }}" />
```